# Two Examples of Cyclic Modules

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Give an example of:
>
> (a) a cyclic $\mathbb R[x]$ module that is three-dimensional over
>   $\mathbb R$.
>
> (b) a cyclic $\mathbb Z[x]$ module with a submodule that is not
>   cyclic.

I've been studying for a test coming up, and I've been having trouble coming up with examples like these.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know a good way to define modules over polynomial rings?

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not really sure I do actually.

Comment: There's a useful alternative definition to an $R$ action on an abelian group $M$. You may be used to that being a map $R \times M \longrightarrow M$ satisfying some axioms, but that can be concisely written as there being a ring homomorphism $R \longrightarrow End_{\mathbb Z}(M)$, the ring of abelian group endomorphisms of $M$. Here, the image of $r \in R$ under this map is meant to represent the multiplication by $r$ endomorphism. In other words, we equip $End_{\mathbb Z}(M)$ with an $R$-algebra structure. Now, what do $R$-algebra maps $R[x] \longrightarrow End_{\mathbb Z}(M)$ look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Question (a)** Let $M=\mathbb{R}^3$, and for each $(a,b,c)\in M$, let $x\cdot(a,b,c)=(0,a,b)$. We can extend this definition to get a map $\mathbb{R}[x]\times M\to M$ that will make $M$ into an $\mathbb{R}[x]$ module. The module will be cyclic, since it will be generated by $(1,0,0)$.

**Question (b)** Let $M=\mathbb{Z}[x]$. $M$ is a cyclic $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ module. Let $I=(2,x)$, i.e. $I$ is the ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ that is generated by $2$ and $x$. Then $I$ is a submodule of $M$, but it is not cyclic.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: quotient rings of the base ring are very common examples of cyclic modules, and ideals of these rings are very common examples of submodules.